# Do we find any (even hazy) references in non-Jewish traditions about Jesus, as promised saviour?

Tags: life-of-jesus, messiah, special-revelation

God prepared Jewish people throughout their history and moulded them according to His requirement so that they become ready for accepting His Saviour for all the mankind. Even then many of His chosen people failed to recognise Jesus as promised Saviour.

Since Jesus was supposed to be the saviour for all humanity, there is every possibility that God would want to reveal His plan of saving humanity, to other non Jewish people around the world. Hence it is likely that God would make aware to other non-Jewish people also, for a need of a saviour for this world. So it is possible that such revelation did came to many other groups of people around the world, yet the same was most probably misinterpreted in the subset of their geographical as well as regional belief system.

One such instance that comes to my mind is close resemblance in some of the details, between Jesus and Krishna. The [recording of these details](http://www.ancient.eu.com/Bhagavad_Gita/) was close to the period (century) of Prophet Isaiah, when very clear references to birth of Jesus were revealed.  While there is no evidence to back up the claim that this story of Krishna was of the events that had already happened, it is surely a shaded reference to Jesus who was to come somewhere in future. It is highly possible that over the years, it was presumed by these groups of people, that whatever was revealed has already come to pass, because of their ignorance of God’s actual plan in that region of the world.

So are there any other such references in non-Jewish traditions where the manifestation Jesus Christ was prophesised?

Comment: Lew Wallace, the author of Ben Hur seemed to think so.  He's got some tradition from each of the wise men, no idea where he came up with that though.

Answer (score 4):

In his book, *Eternity in Their Hearts*, Don Richardson details what he calls "A World Prepared for the Gospel", which is the title of the first section of the book.

**People of the Lost Book**

Chapter 2 is entitled "Peoples of the Lost Book", which details tribes that bemoan the fact that their ancestors had lost "the book" from God.  Some of them looked forward to the day when this book would be restored.

**People with Strange Customs**

Chapter 3 speaks is entitled "Peoples with Strange Customs", which detail the customs of very remote tribes with strikingly similarities to things in the Bible.  In Don Richardson's own experience as a missionary to a remote tribe, he identifies the custom of the "Peace Child".  When he presents Jesus as God's peace child, the tribe responds to the Gospel in a powerful way.

**The Ancient Chinese**

The ancient Chinese also have some interesting writings from Lao Tze and others.  Prior to Mao Tse Tung, the emperor actually offered what was called the Border Sacrifice every year in the Temple of Heaven.  This closely resembles the offering of the Jewish High Priest once a year for the sins of the people.

The Chinese alphabet itself has some extraordinary parallels to Genesis 1-11.  Interestingly enough, the word for righteousness is a combination of two other characters--the word for Lamb and the word for me.  Righteousness is a lamb over/covering me.

Comment: @RyanFrame Good catch!